# Convert 1-channel Mat to 3-channel Mat

Tags: android, opencv

Here is the code snippet:

```
private void loadImage(String path)
{
    originalImage = Highgui.imread(path);

    Log.i(TAG, "Number Of Channels: " + originalImage.channels());

    Mat rgbImage = new Mat();
    sampledImage = new Mat();

    Mat out = new Mat(); // Added
    List<Mat> in = new ArrayList<>();// Added
    in.add(originalImage);// Added
    in.add(originalImage);// Added
    in.add(originalImage);// Added
    Core.merge(in, out);// Added

    Log.i(TAG, "Number Of OUT Channels: " + out.channels());

    Imgproc.cvtColor(originalImage, rgbImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB); // error here
```

‍‍‍‍‍`originalImage` is 1-channel and I need to convert it to 3-channel. The out mat generated from the above code is still 1-channel. How do I convert the out Mat to a 3-channel?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of merging a single channel image thrice, to a single `Mat`, why don't you try to use `cvtColor(in, out, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)`. However I suspect `originalImage = Highgui.imread(path);` would generate you a single channel image, to read a single channel you need to pass `0` flag to imread I guess, But since you are logging `Log.i(TAG, "Number Of Channels: " + originalImage.channels());` the number of channels, So maybe I would be missing something. Your code can be rewritten as (assuming `originalImage` is single channel image):

```
private void loadImage(String path)
{
    originalImage = Highgui.imread(path);
    Mat out = new Mat();

    Log.i(TAG, "Number Of Channels: " + originalImage.channels());

    Imgproc.cvtColor(originalImage, out, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB);

    Log.i(TAG, "Number Of OUT Channels: " + out.channels());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert channel 1 mat to channel 3 using Imgproc.cvtColor() method.
As per the documentation, cvtColor() has 4th parameter -> **dstCn**

> dstCn – number of channels in the destination image; if the parameter is 0, the number of the channels is derived automatically from src and code

So, in your case you can convert original mat in 3 channel mat as below:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(originalImage, rgbImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB,3); // where 3 is channel number
```

for more info, check cvtColor method here : [cvtColor](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html)
Hope it will work !!